# JQuery Auto complete not working in some pages

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am having a strange problem regarding the following code.

I am using jQuery auto complete feature by using the following code. Some times it works perfectly fine giving me the search results in auto complete list in some specific pages.

In other pages than those specific pages, this feature is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#userToSearch" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchUserAutocomplete.do'
    });
});
```

The above code I am using for minLength 3 and search is coming from searchUserAutoComplete.do which maps a spring controller.

Comment: What specific pages? Have you compared the pages it works in to the pages it doesn't? Does your userToSearch element exist in all of them? Does the code?

Comment: Actually, this search is a common page, that is as header. I am using tiles and in body I am loading different pages depending on the menu item in left. After loading some of this pages, the functionality works fine and for some it is not. userToSearch exist in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the auto complete working in these pages in case you reload them. If so, reload these pages using $route.reload or location.reload and let us know if it works